# Video Takes Too Long to Load in My Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, video-player

I'm stuck with a weird problem while using Flutter's [`better_player`](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player) package in my app. I've tried a bunch of different packages like [`video_player`](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player), [`cached_video_player`](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_video_player), and [`better_player`](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player), but no luck. Whenever I try to play a small 1,4mb video from the internet, it takes up to 5s to load and start playing.

## Code

```
import 'package:better_player/better_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class VideoPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<VideoPlayer> createState() => _VideoPlayerState();
}

class _VideoPlayerState extends State<VideoPlayer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BetterPlayer.network(
      "https://dropovercl.s3.amazonaws.com/b7c13ee1-36c6-42ce-857e-fb79a60c7103/856224b4-b678-4bbf-97fc-ef716fe30bed/a132375d-ea99-4930-90c4-bef5efb9ab9b.mp4"
    );
  }
}
```

## What I've tried

**I tested it with two videos:**

- One video is super long, like over 10 minutes, and it starts playing almost instantly for some reason [VIDEO URL](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4).
- Other video is only 11 seconds long and 1,4MB large, but it takes up to 5 seconds to start playing [VIDEO URL](https://dropovercl.s3.amazonaws.com/b7c13ee1-36c6-42ce-857e-fb79a60c7103/856224b4-b678-4bbf-97fc-ef716fe30bed/a132375d-ea99-4930-90c4-bef5efb9ab9b.mp4)

Is there a reason on why first video even tho significantly larger in size (10min & 170mb) loads instantly, and other video (11s & 1,4mb) takes whole 3-5 seconds to load?

Is there a way to load a video in chunks? So that for example first 3s of the video gets loaded and start playing to the user instantly while the remaining of the video is loading in the background?

## Steps to reproduce:

1. Use the Flutter [`better_player`](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player) package to load a video from a custom internet source.
2. Compare the loading time of the two videos mentioned above.
3. Observe the significantly longer loading time for the custom/smaller video.

## Flutter Environment:

- Flutter version: **`Flutter 3.11.0-18.0.pre.65 • channel master`**
- Dart version: **`Dart 3.1.0`**
- Operating System: **Mac OS**
- IDE: **Visual Studio Code**

## Flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.11.0-18.0.pre.65, on macOS 13.4 22F66
   darwin-arm64, locale en-SI)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.81.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

Any insights, suggestions, or guidance on how to address this issue and implement efficient video loading strategies in Flutter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance ❤️

Comment: I saw the same issue and it was marked as resolved at https://www.reddit.com/r/flutterhelp/comments/15s2h76/video_takes_too_long_to_load_in_my_flutter_app/